# Animate width of div bound to data property in Vue

Tags: vue.js, animation, inline-styles

I have this progress bar div, whichs width is bound to the data property result and changes accordingly. At the moment it still jumps, but I want to animate it. I thought of tracking the old and the new Value and injecting it in the css with css variables or just using a setInterval method, but tracking the 2 values seems to get quite complicated and it seemed like a overkill for me. Does anyone have an easier idea?

```
<template>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-value" :style="{ 'width': result + '%' }">
          <h2>{{ result }}%</h2>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["result"],
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.progress {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
}

.progress-value {
  animation: load 3s normal forwards;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* @keyframes load {
  0% {
width: 
  }
  100% {
    width: 
  }
} */
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css transition like this:

```css
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
transition-duration: 1s;
```

And fix the binding:

```html
<div class="progress-value" :style="'width: ' + result + '%'">
```

[See this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<template>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-value" :style="'width: ' + result + '%'">
      <h2>{{ result }}%</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      result: 5
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.increment()
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.result += 10
      if (this.result < 95) {
        setTimeout(this.increment, 1000)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.progress {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
}

.progress-value {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  background: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding the css transition fixed it! And the style binding works both ways for me.